# jQuery Accordion lengthy content

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jquery-ui-accordion

What is the behavior supposed to be when a jQuery accordion section's content is lengthy -- more than will fit on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will scroll off the page.  You can set a fixed height and it will add a scroll bar for any accordion entries that exceed the fixed height if you want everything to stay on one page.

[I have a previous answer about how to control the accordion height properties.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841075/how-can-you-adjust-the-height-of-a-jquery-ui-accordian/2841187#2841187)

Comment: Thank you for the link and the info.